# Could not import 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication' when running python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django

Following a tutorial to use JWT to handle user authentication through tokens.

I have got as far as making changes to my `Settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%P",
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:3000',
)
```

my `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
# router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token)
```

When I try to run `python manage.py migrate` I get the error:

```
ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ImportError: cannot import name 'smart_text' from 'django.utils.encoding' (C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py).
```

I already pip installed `djangorestframework-jwt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt
```

you need this package, the one you installed is not maintained anymore.

uninstall the one you installed and install this package